# why $Log(e^{z})=z$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

$Log(z)=log(\left | z \right |)+iArg(z)$ where $\left \{ z \in \mathbb{C}:-\pi <Imz\leq \pi \right \}$

Now  $Log(e^{z})=log(e^x)+iArg(e^{x+iy})=x+iArg(e^{x+iy})$
my question is why $Arg(e^{x+iy})=y$?
So it can be  $Log(e^{z})=z$

Comment: $e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin(y)$. Therefore $\arg(e^{x+iy})=y$.

Comment: $\operatorname{Log}(e^z)=z$ is the definition (at least for $z$ close enough to the real axis). It is the one thing we categorically know holds true, because that's what $\operatorname{Log}$ _does_. Every rule about how to calculate the complex logarithm, such as your $\operatorname{Log}(z)=\log(\left | z \right |)+i\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ springs from this. Not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that : $$ \mathrm{e}^{x+\mathrm{i}y}=r\,\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\theta} $$

were $ r $ here is $ \mathrm{e}^{x}>0 $, and $ \theta $ is none other than $ y\in\mathbb{R} $.

Therefore : $ \arg\left(\mathrm{e}^{x+\mathrm{i}y}\right)\equiv\theta \equiv y\ \left(\mathrm{mod}\ 2\pi\right) $.

Comment: It would be more accurate to say that $y\in \arg(e^{x+iy})$.

Comment: @Koro Thanks, I've fixed it.

Comment: I don't understand the notation that you have used. Can you please explain that? 

Comment: @Koro It is a congruence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Congruence), $ a\equiv b\ \left(\mathrm{mod}\ 2\pi\right) \iff \left(\exists k\in\mathbb{Z}\right),\ a=b+2k\pi$.

Comment: Ah Okay.  We usually write (mod __) also so got confused. +1

Comment: @Koro Ok, I learned maths in a french-speaking country, I understand that their might be some different notations, I'll fix it.